# Trying to Fetching data from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

Below is my code, i am trying to fetch data from my.sqlite database but it is not executing my if case. It always enters in else condition. What wrong thing i am doing? 
    I am not able to execute my if case i.e. if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuerry, -1, &querryStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)

```
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];
    const char* dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database)==SQLITE_OK)
   {
      const char *sqlQuerry="SELECT * FROM Contacts;";
      sqlite3_stmt *querryStatement;
      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuerry, -1, &querryStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
          NSLog(@"conversion successful....");
          while (sqlite3_step(querryStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
         {
             NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *)    
                        sqlite3_column_text(querryStatement, 0)];

            NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(querryStatement, 1)];

            NSLog(@"DB ID :- %@",addressField);
            NSLog(@"DB NAME :- %@",phoneField);
        }
        sqlite3_reset(querryStatement);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error while conversion....");
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         I tried using FMDB and did it as bellow:
         But my *s and *results object are getting nil value and while statement is not executed

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];

FMDatabase* database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];


FMResultSet *s = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contacts"];
while ([s next]) 
{
    int totalCount = [s intForColumnIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Count : %i", totalCount);
}

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"select * from Contacts"];
```

while([results next]) 
   {

```
    NSString *contact_id  = [results stringForColumn:@"contact_id"]; 
    NSString *name = [results stringForColumn:@"name"]; //
    NSLog(@"User: %@ - %@",name, contact_id);
}
[database close];
```

Comment: Yes i have tried FMDB also but failed ...

Comment: Try one thing, instead of `const char *sqlQuerry="SELECT * FROM Contacts;";`, try using `NSString*sqlStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Contacts"]; const char*sqlStmt=[sqlStatement UTF8String];`, and try using `sqlite3_errmsg()`

Comment: So what is the error?  You never know it might actually tell you what is broken.

Comment: Try naming the fields instead of using a *.

Comment: i tried using field names but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I was going wrong. I created & inserted data to my database using Core Data. At the time of fetching I wanted to fire very complex queries, so I had to switch to SQLite. I was doing everything fine but getting error: `Table not found`.

The actual problem was that `CoreData` changed every table name of my database with a name prepending a "z", so my table name Contacts changed to ZContacts and column names in similar manner. When I opened my sqlite database in SQLite Manager I found where I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace your first *six* lines by the following code:**

```
sqlite3 *database;

NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"DATABASE PATH=%@",databasePath); 

NSFileManager *fn=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;

BOOL success=[fn fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(!success) {
         NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];
         success = [fn copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
                 }

const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database)==SQLITE_OK) 
{

        //. . . . your code...// 
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code but then also problem remains the same, I'm not getting data and else case statement executes giving output:error while conversion....

Comment: Check where is your my.sqlite file saved in project.

Comment: Database name and path is correct and i've checked it and data is also  present in it...

Comment: Try:
**1.** Debug and see if entitySubjects is not nil
**2.** Try Product->Clean, Product->Build then try running, if it doesn't help
**3.** If you have added a new model version, you may have forgotten to set it as "Current Version" and if that's not the case
**4.** Your data may have got corrupted, try deleting it and run again
**5.** Last try is to recreate your model again, something might have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with any sqlite API then you need to report the error using `sqlite3_errmsg()` ([reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)) and this will help you track down your problem.

Change your code to report the error and update your question with the log output:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    NSLog("Failed to open database '%@': %s", databasePath, sqlite3_error(database));
}
```

According to the documentation for `sqlite3_open()` ([here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)):

> .... Otherwise an error code is returned. The sqlite3_errmsg() or
>   sqlite3_errmsg16() routines can be used to obtain an English language
>   description of the error following a failure of any of the
>   sqlite3_open() routines.

Comment: @SurajMirajkar Use the sqlite_error() to find out the reason why you end up in your else-part.